# Initializing an iterated text input using value

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to iterate text inputs using the data from an external JSON file.
Everything works fine but I wasn't able to initialize the value of the text input.
I was not able to edit the value when I initialized the model using ng-init.

**index.html**

```
 <div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="ins in insData | filter:insFilter">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="{{ins.ID}}">{{ins.Name}}</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input id="{{ins.ID}}" data-ng-model="Days" ng-value="{{ins.Days}}" name="{{ins.ID}}" type="text" class="form-control input-md" />
        </div>
 </div>
```

**controllers.js**

```
var baseModule = angular.module('baseModule', []);
baseModule.controller('InsuranceDueCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
function($scope, $http)
{
    $http.get('insurance.json').success(function(data)
    {
        $scope.insData = data;
    });
}
```

**insurance.json**

```
[
{
    "Name" : "First Insurance",
    "ID"   : "1",
    "Days" : "5"
},
{
    "Name" : "Second Insurance",
    "ID"   : "2",
    "Days" : "12"
},
{
    "Name" : "Third Insurance",
    "ID"   : "3",
    "Days" : "8"
},
{
    "Name" : "Fourth Insurance",
    "ID"   : "4",
    "Days" : "15"
},
{
    "Name" : "Fifth Insurance",
    "ID"   : "5",
    "Days" : ""
},
{
    "Name" : "Sixth Insurance",
    "ID"   : "6",
    "Days" : "20"
},
{
    "Name" : "Seventh Insurance",
    "ID"   : "7",
    "Days" : ""
}
```

]

Comment: Just give `data-ng-model="ins.Days"` value will be overridden by ng-model.. and it seems like you want to update the value anyways...

Answer (score 0):

Angular does not work this way.

Using ng-value attribute to initialise value will do nothing.

Your data-ng-model attribute should be used to initialise the value of text input.

And as you are generating controls dynamically the scope variable in controller that will be assigned to data-ng-model should be a JSON object.

You should search more on stackiverflow how to dynamically generate controls in angularjs you will get a good understanding.

Hope it helps :)